# Azure Web App Management - Application Settings via REST

Tags: powershell, azure, configuration, web-config, application-settings

I am aware that it is possible to manage the Application Settings via [CLI Tools](http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#cross-platform) or [PowerShell](http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#powershell).

I am sure I read somewhere that there is a REST API to access them as well, but cannot now find any reference to it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I recently was looking into this.

An amazingly awesome site to checkout is https://resources.azure.com/. I believe that the CLI Tools and PowerShell Tools use this REST API. I actually used that site to help me use the PowerShell Tools.

Also there are some simple examples using C# here http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/12/calling-arm-using-plain-rest.html with the code for that blog here https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/tree/master/HttpClientSample. It will help with authentication.